Issue with Eclipse dark theme - project and class selection windows stay in light mode
I’m experiencing an issue with the dark theme in in Eclipse 2024-03 after I recently updated my Windows 11 system to the 23H2 version. Before the update, I had no issues with the dark theme, but now some windows, such as the Project Explorer and Class Selection dialogs, remain in the light theme. The text selection in the editor also appears in black font with a blue highlight, as if the theme were light instead of dark.
I’ve tried:

Verifying that the dark theme is selected in Eclipse (Window > Preferences > General > Appearance).

Installing the DevStyle plugin to enhance dark theme support.

Trying additional theme plugins, but the issue persists.

Restarting Eclipse with the -clean option to clear any cached settings.

Reinstalling Eclipse completely, but the problem remains the same.


None of these solutions have worked. I have also checked the theme settings in Windows, and the system dark mode is enabled.


Has anyone encountered a similar problem after the 24H2 update? Any suggestions on how to fix this?

I cannot reproduce this with Eclipse 2024-09 and the built-in dark theme on Windows 11. Please note that Eclipse 2024-03 is two releases behind. Please also note that the DevStyle plugin patches Eclipse via loadtime weaving which can cause issues and slow down Eclipse (the vendor of this plugin tries to cheat the open source license of Eclipse by doing so). If you don't like the built-in themes, there are other dark themes that are more ergonomic and don't do this.

Note that I have not yet applied the 23H2 (KB5044380) update.
